# How to check in PHP if the URL Format is an Embed and if its Type is an "audio", "image" or "video"?

Tags: php, embed

*I am trying to use this library (https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed) which allows to retrieve information on the URL in Embed format for example Youtube videos. However, I would first like to check if the URL is of the Audio type, or of the Video type or of the Image type before exploring it with this library.*

**How to find Embed URL type, that is to say check if it is an `audio`, a `photo` or even a `video` ???**

How to check first if the media supports the `embed` format and secondly if it is audio, image or video type ???

I searched the PHP.NET documentation in vain to see if there is a checkoEmbed function but nowhere did I find such a function that could help me check if the URL of a media is `embed`.

**Another word, I want to know if is there a way to check if URL is an Embed before to crawl it and How to get its Type (audio, video or image). So, how to check it in PHP ???**

Thank you please help me.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give some examples of the URLs you're thinking of, and what type they are. Not 100% clear what you mean by "the embed format" either, IMO.

Comment: do you have any example, cases ? so it would be easier to help you out

Comment: _I am trying to use this library (https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed) which allows to retrieve information on the URL in Embed format for example Youtube videos. However, I would first like to check if the URL is of the Audio type, or of the Video type or of the Image type before exploring it with this library._ **So, how to find Embed URL type, that is to say check if it is an audio, a photo or even a video ???**

Comment: Thanks for the update. But did you read the bit where two people asked you for _examples_?

Comment: Anyway unless the URL has some known marker in it which always identifies its type, then you can't tell what kind of content it is without visiting it. As per the ombed spec at https://oembed.com/, you only get the type of resource after you've made the oEmbed-compatible request to the server and received the metadata back.